# Making a another applications's window frontmost and focused

Tags: macos, applescript, core-graphics

I've been trying to get any given window from another Application to become front most and focused.

Here are the two methods I have tried:

**AppleScript**

```
tell application "Safari"
   set index of window "Downloads" to 1
   activate
end tell
```

*Why it doesn't work:* While it seems to change the z-Order, it doesn't change the focus! The previous frontmost window, even if obfuscated, retains focus.

**CoreGraphicServices**

```
CGSWindowOrder(cid, wid, kCGSOrderAbove, nil)
```

*Why it doesn't work:* Without being the Universal Owner, you can't change the order of a window owned by another process. In this case, making myself the Universal Owner is not an option -- I don't want to depose the Dock.

**Recap**

I need to make a window frontmost and focused from one process to another. AppleScript fails to focus, and CGS isn't an option since I don't own the window.

Any solutions/ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this that can work today? Without accessibility enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Accessibility API to send an AXPress action to the AXWindow. Obviously, the user will need to have access for assistive devices turned on.

Comment: Is there any easy to way create an AXWindow using a CGSWindow handle/id?

Comment: Edward: Nope. The only way to get an AXWindow is to find the window by title among the AXApplication's windows. This also means that if two windows have the same title, you're screwed.

Comment: This AX stuff is no longer around I think, is there any non accessibility method for these days? :) Thanks Peter!

Comment: @Noitidart: The Accessibility APIs still exist. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityLowlevel/

Comment: Thanks @Peter you're right. But is it possible without accessiblity, maybe some private CoreGraphics stuff? My users are very newbie (firefox addon users) so they don't know how to turn on/off accesibility (especially granting a specific app access really is hard for them :( )

Comment: @Noitidart: Private interfaces are *more* likely to go away out from under you, not less. There isn't really a good solution there, except to file a bug asking for the usability of the accessibility-permission system to be improved (ideally with specific descriptions of difficulties your users have encountered): https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Thanks @Peter I'm going to buy that 100$ soon I badly need so many things. I got Windows and Linux sorted away but can't release till i have cross platform and OSX is a big chunk.

Comment: @Noitidart: Not sure what $100 you mean? You should be able to use the Apple Bug Reporter with only a (free) developer account; you shouldn't need to join the (not free) Developer Program.

Comment: Oh thanks for that, ill give it a shot. I thought they only help you out if you sing up.

Comment: @Noitidart: You may be thinking of support incidents, which are only available to Developer Program members.

Comment: Ah yeah I was thinking of doing that to ask them for stuff lke "always on top on windows" and stuff would they give me something? And i have another issue where `setApplicaitoniconImage` is not changing the icon that is overlaid ontop of minimized windows as this red arrow in img points out: ![](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/32204eb79b320f3894f6ef3c07a988ad48eb0ba6/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f68735254536b362e706e67)

Comment: @Noitidart: You should file bug reports for those. Here's the info on support incidents, what they're for, and how to use them: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/ (Bug reports and TSIs are not mutually exclusive; it is valid to file a bug report to alert Apple to a problem, then use a TSI to try to unblock yourself.)

Comment: Thanks very much @Hosey! :)